# Best design pattern for data model in restrofit rest android app which json data

Tags: java, android, json, design-patterns, retrofit

I have learned from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE which is best approach for flow in application (use service, content provider etc) but I don't know what is best practice (design pattern) to work with data retried and data received. All data is in JSON.

So I want to develop simple app. The app make request to server to login. In response I get token and JSON which describe a voting. After that I have to sent this complex JSON base on user input. This is kind of form to fill up. A voting system.

```
{
  "data" : {
   "name": "Name of kind of voitng",
   "general_data" : [ {"name": "n1", "value":1}, {"name": "n1", "value":1}],
   "voits": [{"name": "n1", "value":1}, {"name": "n1", "value":1}],
} 
}
```

So I have classes which is mapped to this JSON. But I need also represent these data on the activity. So now I have two classes.

```
    class GeneralDataElementJSON { 
String name; 
int value;
}
    class GeneralDataElementModel { 
String name; 
int value; 
boolean isVoited = false;
}
    class GeneralDataElementView extends View {}
```

Now in my approach I map the retrieved data to instances of *JSON classes after that I convert  instances of *JSON classes into  instances of *Model classes. The  instances of *View classes are adapter for  instances of *Model for display.

After user input I convert  instances of *Model classes into  instances of  *JSON classes and  instances of *JSON classes (using retrofit) are converted to JSON and sent back to server.

So it is complicated. I think that there should be better approach to do that. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do with Retrofit. Just use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate your POJO's (model classes). This will have all your getters and setters and serialized data for you to use and manipulate as you wish.

Let's say you're retrieving a `Data` objects. When you retrieve data with Retrofit, just throw them into a `List<Data>`. Something like the following code:

```
public interface DataService{
  @GET("/{user}/data")
  List<Data> listData(@Path("user") String user);
}

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://your.url.com")
.build();

DataService service = restAdapter.create(DataService.class);    

List<Data> datas = service.listData("your_parameter");
```

From a design standpoint, I find this to be the most elegant way because your POJOs should change as frequently as the API changes (that is, very infrequently). As such, it's OK to auto-generate your code and just have this black-box to reference. The best code is the code you don't have to write. Be careful to not over-architect.